# Can't connect SSH on static IP address

Tags: networking, server, ssh, openssh, static-ip

I have a **default Ubuntu Server 22.04** installation (haven't done anything on it yet).
SSH is working fine with default configuration on server's dynamic local IP.

I then set up a new **netplan** configuration file with static IP as seen here : https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/network-configuration

Here is my **netplan** configuration file `/etc/netplan/99_config.yaml` :

```
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
        - 172.26.50.150/24
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 172.26.50.1
      nameservers:
          search: [example.com, sales.example.com, dev.example.com]
          addresses: [172.26.50.30, 172.26.50.50]
```

I then use `sudo netplan apply` to apply the configuration. Which works as the DHCP ip is not responding anymore, and the new IP pings well.

However :

- I'm not able to connect SSH on the new static IP
- If I revert the **netplan** configuration to the original DHCP one, SSH is working again

My SSH config file is the default **openssh-server** one, with no limitation (ListenAddress etc...)

I tried to `sudo apt-get purge openssh-server` and then `sudo apt-get install openssh-server` as another topic on the internet suggests but I'm still having the same issue.

I tried to have a **netplan** conf that allow DHCP + Static IP, and while both IP respond properly on the network, only DHCP's IP would allow SSH connections.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out I had a duplicate IP on my network, so whenever I was trying to connect to my Ubuntu server I was in fact trying to connect a Windows server that would refuse any SSH attempt. Ashamed but relieved, everything is working fine with another IP address.